# ado.net using same sqlcommand object to execute multiple commands

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

Can any one tell about 
Using same SqlCommand object to execute multiple commands in .net applicaton.

**Situation:**
I have a Truncate table  command which is executed first.
then I will perform SqlBulkcopy operations
then i want the same command object to execute another stored procedure which will
perform some updation or moving the data to different tables.

I dont want to create a new Command object.

One more thing all the three operations are in a transaction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to create a new object. Just specify a new

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT FROM WHERE...";
```

with the neccesary parameters before executing each command.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same SqlCommand object to execute more commands. Just be sure to reset the following properties to appropriate values

- [SqlCommand.CommandText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtext.aspx)
- [SqlCommand.CommandType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype.aspx) - set this to CommandType.StoredProcedure in case you need to execute a stored procedure next.
- [SqlCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) - You can use [SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.deriveparameters.aspx) to overwrite existing parameter information with required parameters, although this would entail an additional call to the server.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this, I believe...

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandText = 
    "SELECT FROM WHERE...; SELECT FROM WHERE...; SELECT FROM WHERE...;";
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you include all operations in one command text "GO" statement between them if you need query segments to be run in separate batches you can use the transactions also with this

```
TRUNCATE TABLE X;
GO

/* do SqlBulkcopy code*/
GO

/* EXECUTE STORED PROC*/
GO
```